# Is there a way to show notification from bash script in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notifications

Most of the application can show nicely formatted notification on events that appear on top right corner of the screen. I'm about to write a bash script that will do fairy long processing in the background and I really want to know when it is finished. How can I show that nice notification from a bash script?

Comment: [How can I trigger a notification when a job/process ends?](http://superuser.com/q/345447/241386)

Comment: Bonus question: Can you put the notification on certain output only? What if you use screen mirroring?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If you're using the new notification system in Jaunty, you want the **notify-send** command

```
notify-send - a program to send desktop notifications

SYNOPSIS

With notify-send you can sends desktop notifications to the user via
a notification daemon from the command line.  These notifications can be
used to inform the user about an event or display some form of information
without getting in the user's way.

OPTIONS

-u, --urgency=LEVEL
Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).

-t, --expire-time=TIME
    Specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the notification.
-i, --icon=ICON[,ICON...]
    Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.
-c, --category=TYPE[,TYPE...]
    Specifies the notification category.
```

Comment: Thanks, just found it myself :) apt-get install libnotify-bin have to be run before to get it.

Comment: How does the root user send a message from crons, init.d, etc?

Comment: Eg: notify-send Test "Hello World"

Comment: The --expire-time parameter does not work on Ubuntu thanks to this "feature" (bug).  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508

Comment: I found that `notify-send` is inhibited during video/audio playback. While this is a valid use case, if you still want to see them then  **--urgency=critical** must be added.

Comment: I'm using jessie (Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+), on raspberry, install notify 'libnotify-bin', but it don't bring any notification! -> notify-send Test "Hello World"

Comment: Thanks buddy. I used this to send me a notification every 10 minutes to blink eyes using cron as a reminder to follow 20-20 (10-10 rule in my case) rule. ;)

Comment: To make it pop up a window with an "OK" and "Cancel" button use `notify-send --expire-time=0 "Hello World"` or `notify-send -t 0 "Hello world"`

Comment: Note, however, that otherwise the `--expire-time` or `-t` option is worthless (ignored), unfortunately, and the default of 10 sec or so applies to all notifications regardless of what you want. Pretty stupid if you ask me! https://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout

Comment: I couldn't take it; I had to write my own answer :) https://superuser.com/a/1310142/425838

Answer (score 42):

Found another way, through [Zenity](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Zenity)

```
echo 'message:hi' | zenity --notification --listen
```

or like this:

```
zenity --notification --text "System update necessary!"
```

(This also has the benefit of already being installed on Ubuntu.)

Comment: I like Zenity in that it supports user interactions for dialogs (unlike notify-send)

Comment: Doing it in .profile causes an error: `The name org.freedesktop.Notifcations was not provided by any .service file`. Otherwise it works well. Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 19):

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04. Screenshots from Ubuntu 20.04.

1. **[WORKS WELL] Popup notification that auto-closes after 4~10 seconds (somehow tied to your OS settings?):**

   ```bash
   notify-send "Hello world"
   ```

   [image]
   Source: https://superuser.com/a/31919/425838
2. **Popup window with buttons to click:**

   1. **Window does NOT get auto-focus:**
      Source: myself; note: for older Unity-based versions of Ubuntu, such as 16.04, `-t` [is ignored for all values except 0--how stupid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout). :(. For newer Gnome-based versions of Ubuntu, such as 18.04 or 20.04, `-t` is ignored entirely. Therefore, on older Unity-based versions of Ubuntu, such as 16.04, using `-t 0` causes buttons to show up, but on newer Gnome-based versions, it does NOT. That means that for the Ubuntu 20.04 screenshot shown below, the behavior and look of `notify-send -t 0 "Hello world"` is exactly identical to `notify-send "Hello world"` above.

      ```bash
      notify-send -t 0 "Hello world"
      ```

      [image]

      On Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 or later, just add `-u critical` to the command instead to get it to *stay open indefinitely until you click anywhere on it!*:

      ```bash
      notify-send -u critical "Hello world"
      ```

      [image]
      Source: @lucidbrot's comment below this answer, plus my own testing.
   2. OR **Window DOES get auto-focus:**

      ```bash
      zenity --info --title "Hello" --text "World"
      ```

      Note: the window will NOT close until you click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
      [image]
      Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/804475/327339
3. **[MY FAVORITE] The window auto-closes after the specified `--timeout` in seconds, OR after you click the "OK" button!**

   ```bash
   zenity --info --title "Hello" --text "World" --timeout=2
   ```

   Note: the window WILL automatically close after the specified timeout above, in seconds!
   [image]
   Source: myself reading the man pages: `man zenity`
4. **[super ugly-looking]**

   ```bash
   xmessage 'hello world'
   ```

   Note: the window will NOT close until you click the <kbd>okay</kbd> button.
   [image]
   Source: http://www.linux-commands-examples.com/xmessage

### Play sounds too

1. If you want to play sounds too, along with the window popup, to signify the completion of a command or something, see my other answers here:

   1. [AskUbuntu.com: How to make a sound once a process is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete/1213564#1213564)
   2. My "Bash one-line alarm script" here: [Ask Ubuntu: Alarm clock for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500350/327339). In it, I use the `zenity` popup window.

### See also

1. My ["Bash one-line alarm script"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500350/327339) from the command-line, and my custom `alarm_timer <seconds> <alarm message>` function there.

Comment: My notification with `-t 0` disappears by itself unless the level is `critical` just like the others. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. But the other options work great, and the `[super ugly-looking]` made me laugh

Comment: very detail. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

For KDE users:

```
$ kdialog --title "Long process completed!" --passivepopup "This popup will disappear in 5 seconds" 5 &
```

Comment: Is it possible to set an icon for the notification?

Answer (score 12):

There's also **[xmessage](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xmessage.1.html)** that will pop-up a window, so it should work on any X11 system.

**Pro:** It also allows interactively prompting the user with buttons.

**Con:** Like any pop-up alert, it *typically* receives focus, so if you're in the middle of typing it can disappear before you read the message.

Comment: Con: It looks ugly as hell, and also is a super tiny window which is not always obvious to the user. Anyways, it is universal though. :)

Comment: xmessage doesn't work in Fedora though. Its not installed by default.

Comment: It's not available in the default Xorg installation of Arch Linux either.

Comment: You can also get a popup window with an "OK" and "Cancel" button via `notify-send --expire-time=0 "Hello World"` or `notify-send -t 0 "Hello world"`. Otherwise, however, the `-t` option is ignored due to some stupid "design decisions": https://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout

Comment: I couldn't take it; I had to write my own answer :) https://superuser.com/a/1310142/425838

Answer (score 4):

There exists a cross-platform solution called [Yfiton](https://github.com/yfiton/yfiton):

```
$ yfiton -n desktop -Pmessage="Lunch time!" -Pposition=TOP_RIGHT
```

Answer (score 3):

In a shell script, you can also call the osd_cat utility from libxosd.

Comment: This is a little bit different as it doesn't use ubuntu desktop notifications.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative that you can use with any Linux distribution and any WM/DE.