# Pop-Up Notification when time reaches 4:00PM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, notifications, notify-osd

I was wondering if there was a way to display a notification or something  from the command line at a certain time. Like when the clock strikes 4:00pm. It would be nice if it would display it using Ubuntu's notify-osd tool:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to know the exact second you are done with work for the day?

Comment: No. Who gets off at 4:00? I actually need to tell myself to goto bed.

Comment: @Lucas Aardvark : LOL.

Comment: I get off work at 4:00pm.. then again, I get in to work at 7am most days..

Comment: This is great.  I was just asking about something like this at https://askubuntu.com/questions/936645/how-to-make-my-ubuntu-16-04-system-pop-up-a-one-time-to-do-reminder

Comment: Here I am up still at 3:55am.  I suppose I should have had this tell me to go to bed at 3.  ;-)    btw, can you believe you posted this 7 years and 10 months ago?  Hello from the Future; July 2017.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As many of the other commenters said, the best way to do this on a daily basis is to use cron, but if you are only wanting to do it for one day, or sporadically, you can use the `at` command:

```
echo 'notify-send "Work day is done!"' | at 4:00PM
```

You can use `at` in a variety of ways, including as a tea timer:

```
echo 'notify-send "Get your tea!"' | at now + 3 minutes 
echo 'notify-send "Meeting in 1 hour with the big boss!"' | at 1pm tomorrow
```

It's quite useful for those one-off commands.

Check the [at manpage](https://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/) for more syntax goodness.

Comment: You can't type the command on the after the invocation of "at." You have to do something like 

echo 'notify-send "Work day is done!"' | at 4:00PM

Comment: True, I forgot about that little annoyance.

Comment: I liked your solution best because it can be easily changed and doesn't require root access to edit `/etc/crontab`

Comment: You need add DISPLAY variable to environment to work with `at` or `cron`.
Type this: `echo 'export DISPLAY=:0; notify-send "Enjoy!"' | at 04:00 PM `.

Comment: You need to [`apt install libnotify-bin`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libnotify-bin) to use [`notify-send`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libnotify-bin/notify-send.1.en.html).

Comment: Is there a way to use this from the "Run a command" (ALT + F2) prompt? `notify-send` works from there but `echo` and `at` does not seem to.

Answer (score 15):

Use [**notify-send**](https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu/31919#31919) to send the notification. Set it up as a cron job.

Comment: But that doesn't work out of box. `notify-send` requires some env variables whichr are not available from cron by defaualt?

Answer (score 12):

You can send commands to notify-osd like so:

```
notify-send "Go to bed!"
```

A crontab for daily notification at 4pm would look like so:

```
0 16 * * * /home/username/notify.sh
```

Comment: You might need to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable before running notify-send. See https://askubuntu.com/a/346580

Answer (score 0):

You can always set up a cron job to run a script @ 0400hrs. The tricky thing here, is to find out what command to use to popup a window (ala net send for windows), or to do anything to notify you to go off to bed.

notify-osd doesn't seem to support command-line prompt generation, you might want to try [LinPopup2](http://linpopup2.sourceforge.net/)...

Answer (score 0):

if you use a program like anacron (warns you even if the computer is not running so useful more than cron for desktops and notebooks etc ) um then i use Zenity its a notification program here is my site for it with a few examples http://sites.google.com/site/venvirupa/yadandyin

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using gnome-do. There are a few plugins there that can be used - remember the milk (RTM) is one.