# How can I trigger a notification when a job/process ends?

Tags: command-line, unix, process, notifications

The place I work at has commands that take a long time to execute.

Is there a command/utility that I can use to notify me when the command execution is over? It could be a popup window or maybe a little sound.

Comment: @slhck's accepted answer is cool - I should have realized that `fg;say "Job finished"` would work.   But... is there any way that it can be further automated - i.e. ring the bell or notify after completion of any job that takes more than a threshold like a minute?  Is there a shell variable, e.g. in bash, that is elapsed time of the last command?

Comment: ... 2 hours later, found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862510/how-can-the-last-commands-wall-time-be-put-in-the-bash-prompt/1862762#1862762 ... put  '(( $timer_show > ${LONG_RUNTIME:-300} )) && say "long running job completed"' in timer_stop  ... next, add to emacs' compile commands ... and notify my Pebble watch (I hate phone notifications)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Generally, if you know this *before* running the command, you can just start it with:

```
command; command-after &
```

This will execute the `command-after` *after* the previous command has exited (regardless of its exit code). The `&` will start it in background.

If you care about a successful or failure exit, respectively use:

```
command && command-after-only-if-success &
command || command-after-only-if-fail &
```

If the command has *already* started you may use job control to suspend it, then return it to the foreground with `fg` chained with your notification:

```
command
# enter Ctrl-z
fg ; command-after
```

---

Now … what you want to do after this depends on your environment.

- On **any system**, you can ["ring" the terminal bell](http://fisica.ehu.es/ref/unixfaq.html#2.14). Depends on your exact system what really works (BSD vs. GNU Linux, etc.), but `tput bel` should do. I couldn't reliably test it right now, though. Search for "ring bell" to find out more.
- On **Mac OS X**, you could use AppleScript to pop up a Finder dialog:

  ```
  osascript -e 'tell Application "Finder" to display dialog "Job finished" '
  ```

  You could have it say something to you:

  ```
  say "Job finished"
  ```

  Or you could use Mountain Lion's notification system:

  ```
  sudo gem install terminal-notifier # <= only need to do this once
  terminal-notifier -message "Job finished!" -title "Info"
  ```
- In **GNOME**, [`zenity`](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity) can show a GTK dialog box, called from the command line. See also this Stack Overflow question: [showing a message box from a bash script in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/showing-a-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux). It can be installed through your favorite package manager.

  ```
  zenity --info --text="Job finished"
  ```
- Some distributions might have [`xmessage`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xmessage/). Specifically for GTK environments, there is [`gxmessage`](http://crash.ihug.co.nz/~trmusson/programs.html).
- On desktop enviroments that implement the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/), such as **Ubuntu** and **GNOME**, there's a notification system that you can trigger with [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/notify-send.1.html) (part of `libnotify`).

  ```
  notify-send "Job finished!"
  ```
- **KDE** uses `kdialog`, for example:

  ```
  kdialog --passivepopup 'Job finished'
  ```

Comment: I'm fiddling around with notify-send and xmessage. Both of them seem to be interesting! Here's the next thing I'm looking for - http://superuser.com/questions/345463/getting-the-name-of-the-previous-process

Comment: on Mac OS X, you can also use the command-line utility "say". there are also many voices available, check "say -h" ;)

Comment: Why are you suggesting that "command-after" should be run asynchronously?  Did you mean to say `(command; command-after) &`?

Comment: This solution is for Konsole users and isn't a perfect solution as it relies on your command either being verbose until it is complete, or completely silent (no output) until it completes at which point the prompt returns. However, this is exactly what I needed when I came looking for help. You can configure Konsole to pop-up a notification, play a sound, etc. Then you have to turn on shell monitoring. Monitor for silence if your command outputs a bunch of stuff until it completes, or silence if it doesn't print out anything and then the shell returns.

Comment: Also note that you can configure different responses for different things: silence, activity, non-zero return value, Just click Settings->Configure Notifications...and you can pop up a notification, play a custom sound, log a file, run a command -- pretty versatile -- though I wish there were more actions -- included session finished (regardless of exit status)

Comment: Sweet! added to my .bashrc as an alias :D

Comment: notify-send is part of libnotify and is relevant to Gnome and any other desktop enviroment that implements the desktop notification standard

Comment: @CurlyCorvus I'm sorry your edit got rejected; it was good. I applied it to the post. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Since 2018 the `zenity` answer gives a "This is discouraged" warning, which can be suppressed using https://askubuntu.com/a/1192137/435408.

Answer (score 22):

On unix-like systems you can ring the audible-bell:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

Comment: This is really useful in addition to a message notification on mac

Comment: same as `tput bel`

Answer (score 9):

I created a simple tool, for MacOS X, that does exactly this. https://github.com/vikfroberg/brb

**Installation**

```
$ npm install -g brb
```

**Instructions**

```
$ sleep 3; brb
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote `ntfy` for exactly this purpose. It is **cross-platform** and can **automatically** send notifications when long running commands finish.

If you have Python's `pip` (most Linux distros and MacOS have it), here's how to install it and enable automatic notifications:

```
$ sudo pip install ntfy
$ echo 'eval "$(ntfy shell-integration)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ # restart your shell
```

Check it out at http://ntfy.rtfd.io

In addition to that, it also can:

- supress automatic notifications when the terminal is in the foreground (X11, iTerm2 & Terminal.app supported and enabled by default)
- send cloud-based notifications (Pushover, Pushbullet, and XMPP)
- be used to send notifications when a process ends (not the aforementioned automatic support)
- manually send notifications (good for use in scripts!)

Comment: Good on you.  This is really the most usable answer.

Comment: I agree. I use it to display a notification on my desktop and push the notification to my phone at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

To get a sound notification you can use `spd-say "Some text"`. Example:

```
some-command; spd-say "Yo"
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not have the speech-dispatcher pre-installed, you can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher
```

Comment: What OS? I don't see it on Mac or Ubuntu

Comment: @EdwardFalk I am using Ubuntu

Comment: OK, I'm using a pretty old version, so maybe it's in newer versions.

Comment: It is just a text-to-speech application. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher`. Or use alternatives http://askubuntu.com/questions/501910/how-to-text-to-speech-output-using-command-line

Comment: Ahh, not installed by default? I should have thought about that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @milkovsky at least on Ubuntu 14.04 it is pre-installed: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest

Answer (score 5):

Although other answers already covered most of the ways to get notifications on a finished job, I want to give my two cents since you asked your question in the following format:

> The place I work at has commands that take a long time to execute.

I have the same problem. Sometimes something can run for 15 minutes.

I have the following function in my .bashrc:

```
# push a notification to your phone. can be handy if you're running a
# build and you want to be notified when it's finished.
push() {
    curl -s -F "token=PUSHOVER_TOKEN" \
    -F "user=PUSHOVER_USER" \
    -F "title=terminal" \
    -F "message=$1" https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

This uses the Pushover app in order to push a notification to my phone.
This way I can go to lunch or enter a meeting and still get notified on jobs I started on my computer before I left.

I use it in the following manner:

```
command_to_run && push "yes! command finished successfully!" || push "awww man! something failed :-("
```

So, if the command returns a correct exit code, the first push will be executed. On an error, the second one will be executed.

Ofc you need to create a user at Pushover, and register an app to send notifications from
https://pushover.net/

hope this helped!

Comment: OK, so "pushover" is a web service that sends notifications to phones that have the "pushover" app installed?

Comment: it's a web service that sends notifications to **phones, computers, & everything with a modern web browser**. So, you can have pushover open on your PC and phone and be notified on all devices. neat, huh? :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have just begun using [notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/) for desktop notifications from Cygwin. It's a command line notification app for Windows.

Example:

```
ls -l && /c/notifu-1.6/notifu64 /m "This is a simple Notifu message."
```

Answer (score 3):

For Linux, there is a nifty trick to do this automatically without having to type a command for notification every time.

First install autokey. This helps defining actions for different keystrokes.

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Now, define a new phrase in autokey and assign the hotkey as Alt+Enter. Add this phrase:

```
; notify-send "Job finished!" &
  #
```

Note that a new line after the first line is important.

Also, add a window filter. I use guake and terminal. Include whatever other terminal you use.

```
.*(guake)|(Terminal).*
```

You're done!!

Now, everytime whenever you need to get notifications for a command, run it using Alt+Enter instead of Enter/Return.

Source: http://dotpad.blogspot.in/2014/12/notification-when-command-finished.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use csh or tcsh as your interactive shell, you can use the `notify` command:

```
% long-running-command &
[1] 14431
% notify %1
% 
(later, when the command finishes)
[1]    Done                          long-running-command
```

You can achieve a similar effect in bash with `set -b` or `set -o notify`.

This probably doesn't meet your requirements, since all it does is print a message; I dont' think it can be configured to pop up a window or ring the bell.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid looking at the shell to find out if a job finished. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

On systems with 'awk' try

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "\a" }'
```

was the only one to work for me.

Comment: That's just a verbose way of echoing `\a` ([trinth's answer](http://superuser.com/a/486020/300383)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `npm` then [node-notifier](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) provide a **cross-platform solution**.

```
notify -t "Agent Coulson" --icon https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/master/example/coulson.jpg -m "Well, that's new. "
```

#### Preview

- Linux KDE

[image: Linux KDE]

- Windows

[image: Windows]

- Mac OS

[image: mac]

- Growl

[image: Growl]

Answer (score 1):

Wish I'd noticed this thread years ago. My solution was essentially the same as slhck's, but I wrote a script. I use it all the time. Posting here to share it.

```
#!/bin/bash

msg='all done'
quiet=false
if [ "$1" = '-q' ]; then quiet=true; shift; fi
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then msg="$*"; fi

echo -ne "\x1b]0;$msg\a"
if [ -x /usr/bin/zenity ]; then
  unset WINDOWID
  exec zenity --info --text="$msg"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/xmessage ]; then
  exec xmessage -nearmouse "$msg"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/osascript ]; then
  if ! $quiet; then say "done" &; fi
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to display dialog \"$msg\""
else
  echo $msg
fi
```

One small bit of explanation: the string `"\x1b]0;$msg\a"` is the ANSI escape sequence to put the message in the title bar of the window from which it was executed. I find it quite handy sometimes to be able to see which window it was that the message came from.

Answer (score 1):

So this comes fairly late, but I've started using a system to do this:
I have a bash script which executes whatever command is passed to it afterwards

http://somesh.io/2017/02/19/get-notified-when-long-commands-are-done-executing-on-ubuntu/

```
#!/bin/bash


# file location : /usr/bin/n

set +e


# $@ executes whatever command is typed after the filename

$@


notify-send "Task Completed"
```

and then i simply prepend n

```
n bundle install
n npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Zsh, you can find [zsh notify](https://github.com/marzocchi/zsh-notify) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can show a notification on your terminal itself.

This shows a notification on the lower-right corner for 5 seconds and then disappears. Without blocking.

[image]

```bash
# write_message
# - write a message on the lower right corner of the terminal
function write_message () {
  local message="  $@  "

  function __write () {
    local message="$1"
    local message_length=${#message}

    local terminal_width=$(tput cols)
    local terminal_height=$(tput lines)

    # CSI sequences
    local csi="\033["
    local reset="${csi}0m"
    local set_bg_color="${csi}44m"
    local set_fg_color="${csi}30m"
    local move_cursor_to_right="${csi}${terminal_width}G"
    local move_cursor_to_bottom="${csi}${terminal_width};${terminal_height}H"
    local save_cursor_position="${csi}s"
    local restore_cursor_position="${csi}u"
    local move_cursor_to_left="${csi}${message_length}D"

    # if --no-backgound is passed, don't set the background color
    if [[ "${2-}" == "--no-background" ]]; then
      local set_bg_color=""
    fi

    echo -ne "${save_cursor_position}"
    echo -ne "${move_cursor_to_bottom}${move_cursor_to_right}${move_cursor_to_left}"
    echo -ne "${set_bg_color}${set_fg_color}${message}${reset}"
    echo -ne "${restore_cursor_position}"
  }

  # clean up after 5 seconds
  function __clean_up () {
    sleep 5
    local message_length=${#message}
    local blank_spaces=$(printf "%${message_length}s")
    __write "$blank_spaces" --no-background 
  }

  __write "$message"
  
  # clean up in the background
  # run in a subshell to avoid showing 'job control' output
  (__clean_up &)

  # clean up internal functions
  unset -f __write
  unset -f __clean_up
}

write_message hello there
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `alert`, Works on Linux.

```
>any-command; alert
```

It gives a notification as in the image.
[alert notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfjTd.png)

Comment: From which package?