# Getting the name of the previous process

Tags: unix, process

I'm trying to generate notifications when certain commands finish execution. I'm trying to use `xmessage` or `notify-send` to generate this notification.

Right now, I'm trying it this way:

```
command; notify-send ...;
```

But I might have multiple such commands running – I want to distinguish between them. So I'm trying to get the PID and name of the process that finished. The problem is, the two processes (`<command>` and `notify-send`) aren't related.

Any hints or pointers on what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a notifier script (`~/bin/notifyme`)...

```
#!/bin/bash
(eval "$@")
notify-send "$1 finished" "Command returned $?."
```

...or a function (`~/.bashrc`):

```
notifyme() {
    (eval "$@")
    notify-send "$1 finished" "Command returned $?."
}
```

This is the easiest way.

Comment: That seems to get everything done.

Comment: Is there a way to get auto completion to work? like notify _partialcommand_ <tab> etc?