# How can I trigger a notification from a remote terminal in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, notifications, iterm2

I am running a long process on a remote shell. I would like to trigger a notification when the process is complete. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/345447/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-when-a-job-process-ends) does not suffice, because the long command is on a remote server, so it cannot call terminal-notifier.

I can get close to my desired outcome by using an iTerm2 trigger. For example if I run the following on the remote server and set up an iTerm2 trigger for __FINISHED__:

```
./long_process && echo "\__FINISHED__"
```

This has the undesirable feature that every time I scroll back to this command in my editor or my code (I'm running code in an emacs shell), the notification triggers.

One solution might be some kind of text notification that iTerm2 will recognize, but that will not appear in an emacs scrollback buffer.

Comment: `echo "__FIN""ISHED__"`

Comment: Halfway there - it prevents notifications when i scroll through my code, but doesn't prevent undesirable notifications if i scroll through my output window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not specified what kind of notification you want nor what OS the remote server is running so I am going to have to make some assumptions here. I will assume you don't really care what type of notification it is as long as you are notified and that the remote server is running some flavor of *nix.

1. Send yourself an email. If `sendmail` is configured on the server, you could do

   ```
   ./long_process && echo "Job done" | sendmail pnj@yourdomain.com
   ```
2. ssh back to your local machine (assuming this is possible) and make it talk to you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127977/1081936) for more cool ways of making OSX beep at you.

   ```
   ./long_process && ssh you@local.ip say "Yo! All done"
   ```

   or

   ```
   ./long_process && ssh you@local.ip terminal-notifier -message "Job finished!" -title "Info"
   ```

   If you are connecting from a dynamic IP **and** you have configured your router so that you can ssh to that dynamic IP, you can do this (assuming you are only currently connected from your remote machine):

   ```
   ip=$(who | grep $USER | perl -lne 's/\\((.+?)\\)\s*$//; print "$1"' | tail -n 1) &&
    ./long_process && ssh you@$ip terminal-notifier -message "Job finished!" -title "Info"
   ```

   You can set up password-less ssh in the [normal way](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/). It should not be affected by the dynamic IP. Once you have done so, the code above will work.
3. Use [pushover](https://pushover.net/) and send a notification to your Android or iOS device (if you have one)

   ```
   ./long_process && pushover.pl "All done"
   ```

Comment: Using [`say` over SSH](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/im_an_idiot.png) is really nice on Macs.

Comment: @slhck heh, yeah I'd read that one :).

Comment: #2 is the concept i'm looking for, but the local machine is a laptop and has a dynamic IP address. Ideally I want something like terminal-notifier, i.e. a small, silent popup window. Even if the remote shell knows the spawning process, I'm not sure how ssh would work without entering my password each time, given the dynamic IP.

Comment: @pnj see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon that does it, after fixing the backslashes in the perl expression that superuser ate up.

Comment: To get the IP of ssh client, you may use `echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'`.

Answer (score 7):

You can `echo` a bell - `\a` in the remote terminal:
`./long_process ; echo -e '\a'`

Some terminal emulators will play some sort of sound and might show a notifications. 
iTerm2, in particular, will show a notification and play a sound, if process' tab is not focused.

Also, notice that I used `;` to separate commands. This way you will be notify even when command returns non-zero status while `&&` will only run if command succeeds.

Comment: Simple and legendary for iTerm2

Answer (score 1):

There's a really easy way to cause iTerm2 to bounce in the dock until you switch over to it. It's great. To use it, you just need to use iTerm2 and be able to install software on the host you're ssh'd into. Here's how you do it,

1. SSH into the host.
2. Install Shell Integration for iTerm2. On the Mac version of iTerm2 you do this by selecting iTerm2->Install Shell Integration. More info about how to install [here](https://iterm2.com/documentation-utilities.html) if you need it.
3. Execute your command

```
./long_process && it2attention start
```

4. You can also try

```
./long_process && it2attention fireworks
```