# Linux: w (who) command top-like monitor

Tags: linux, command-line, display, packages

Is there a monitor like `top` but for the `w` (`who`) command? It's ok if it's a package that needs to be installed. Any Linux flavor. I'd like to have a simple CLI real-time monitor of users logged into the system along with what they're doing. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several possibilities. Those that come to my mind immediately are all based in the idea to periodically execute the `w` command (hence, strictly speaking they are no real-time monitors, but top also refreshes the current processes only periodically):

1. Shell based (bash syntax)

   Infinite loop that executes `w` every second:

   ```
   while true; do
      clear
      w
      sleep 1
   done
   ```
2. There's also a dedicated program for that purpose, called `watch`:

   ```
   watch -n 1 "w"
   ```
3. While possibility 1 and 2 usually work *out-of-the-box* on a standard GNU/Linux system, there is also a program called [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/index.php). Although in the first place designed for another purpose,

   > The program MultiTail lets you view one or multiple files like the
   >   original tail program. The difference is that it creates multiple
   >   windows on your console (with ncurses). It can also monitor wildcards:
   >   if another file matching the wildcard has a more recent modification
   >   date, it will automatically switch to that file.

   it can also execute a program periodically:

   ```
   multitail -r 1 -l "w"
   ```

Both, `watch` and `multitail` can also highlight the differences compared to the previous run, please check the man pages for the corresponding (and much more) options.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had already been doing #1 but figured there might be a better tool. I like finding out about the other options, thanks again!

Comment: `eol="$(tput el)";clear; while true ; do w | sed -re "s/^(.*)$/$eol \1 /" ;sleep 1 ; tput home ; done` - a variant for the first above.

Answer (score 1):

The last command acts by reading /var/log/wtmp. You can set up a watch on it by means of*inotifywait*(part of the package *inotify-tools) as follows:

```
   while inotifywait -e close_write /var/log/wtmp ; do /path/to/executable/script; done
```

where /path/to/executable/script is some a script (made executable by *chmod 755 script*) which will do some highly noticeable action to attract your attention, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/345447/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-when-a-job-process-ends/345455#345455) for some suggestions.