# How can I flash the screen to indicate a CMD process has completed?

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I'm running a process on a remote Windows 8.1 PC through CMD, and have a Remote Desktop window open to monitor it. That window is usually in the background.

How can I have CMD display a visual cue that a process has finished?

I found a thread with a few possible options:

`command; command-after &`

`command && command-after-only-if-success &
command || command-after-only-if-fail &`

But am concerned this could affect the metadata of the process, or wouldn't trigger at all if the process simply completes and doesn't show a success or failure.

Is there a way to set CMD.exe to display a visual indication by default?

[How can I trigger a notification when a job/process ends?](https://superuser.com/questions/345447/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-when-a-job-process-ends)